# Does a moving current apply an electrical force on a charge moving perpendicular to it?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am a high school student and I am currently studying magnetic effects of electric current. The question which I have is what kind of forces will a moving current apply on a charge moving perpendicular to it. Is it just magnetic force, or electrical force too?

Comment: Yes, it can exert electric force; a non-zero electric field can appear if the observer moves to a different inertial frame. It is a consequence of special theory of relativity (See this link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity).  In this problem, if the observer is at rest wrt  positive charges in the current carrying wire, then electric force exerted on the moving charge will be zero and the Lorentz force will be due to magnetic field only.

Answer (score -1):

This situation which we take into consideration has a couple of variables to be aware about.

1. The most obvious one: ELECTRIC FIELD- a current carrying wire produces an electric field exerts force on the charge moving perpendicular to the wire, i.e. F= Q.E
2. The 2nd factor to note here is: MAGNETIC FIELD- a current carrying wire also produces a magnetic field (circular in this case) around the wire which also exerts a force on the moving charge i.e. F= Q(V cross product B).
   So basically both , magnetic and electric forces will be applied on the moving charge and their resultant can be simply found by taking their vector sum.
   NOTE: THERE IS NOTHING LIKE A MOVING CURRENT , CURRENT ITSELF REFERS TO A MOVING CHARGE.
   CHEERS!!!